# Concatenating a string to make it a formua [sic]

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to combine a range and an array:

```
letters = "a".."c"
code = ["..--", "--..", "----"]
```

to populate a hash `letter_code`. It should look like:

```
{"a" => "..--", "b" => "--..", "c" => "----"}
```

This is my code:
    letters = "a".."c"
    code = ["..--", "--..", "----"]
    letter_code = {}
    x = 0

```
while x < letters.to_a.length
  "letter_code[ #{letters.to_a[x]} ]=#{code[x]}"
  x += 1
end
puts "#{letter_code}"
```

Why does the concatenation return an empty string?

Comment: You are perhaps misunderstanding the word "concatenate".

Comment: @sawa `puts "#{letter_code}"` prints an empty string. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks, I got it now. The OP left `{}`, and it was confusing.

Comment: What's a "formua"? Also, you're talking about string, but your code works with a hash. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code doesn't work, because string interpolation or string concatenation generates strings. It does not magically evaluate the created string.

I would do something like this:

```
letters = "a".."c"
code = ["..--", "--..", "----"]

Hash[letters.zip(code)]
#>= { "a" => "..--", "b" => "--..", "c" => "----" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
"letter_code[ #{letters.to_a[x]} ]=#{code[x]}"
```

is not doing anything to `letter_code`. It just evaluates `letters.to_a[x]` and `code[x]`, and interpolates them in a string. Therefore, `letter_code` remains as `{}`, and `{}.to_s`, which `puts` calls, is an empty string.

If you want to change `letter_code` by that line, change it to:

```
letter_code[letters.to_a[x]] = code[x]
```

although it is still a terrible code.